# Windows AKS - Copy config files during container startup

Tags: azure-aks

Trying to setup our .NET framework application in Windows AKS and need an elegant way to pass in ApplicationSettings.config & Connectionstrings.config as per environment setup.. trying to use life-cycle hooks & init containers but no luck so far..

any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: whats wrong with init containers, they are meant for that exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When delivering applications in a containerized format such as Docker image on k8s cluster a common pattern is that configuration is read from environment variables.

When drawing configuration from environment variables at runtime, you can set up your pods so that [data stored in ConfigMaps is injected into environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data).

If you want to avoid a code change, here is an excellent article on [generating your config files based on environment variables](https://anthonychu.ca/post/overriding-web-config-settings-environment-variables-containerized-aspnet-apps/) using a startup script.